# Delaying execution within an event - java

Tags: java, multithreading, events, wait

I got an ***EVENT_A*** asking for user name and password in my java client side code triggered by server side C code. A message from server is triggering this and the content of the message is used by the client for further execution.

Now i got an auto logout function added to my application triggered in client by ***EVENT_B***. Just after execution of the ***EVENT_B*** the server is sending ***EVENT_A***. But i have to delay this ***EVENT_A*** until i get a consent from server saying it is login time, say till I get an ***EVENT_C***.

One other thing about the application is this whole process is multi threaded. So i need to delay and keep the object containing ***EVENT_A*** with the server side message ie; i cant just go and initialise another object. I need to call some wait inside ***EVENT_A*** after storing the message from server side in some variable. This should wait until ***EVENT_C*** is triggered in another thread and notified.

**Q)** What is the design pattern to follow for this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared lock object in both places. When you get EVENT_A, call `wait` method on the lock object. When you get EVENT_B, call `notifyall` method on lock object. This should do the job.